# WPF DropShadow Effect disapear when setting background color of control

Tags: wpf, styles, dropshadow

In this example, I have a `TextBlock` with a `DropShadowEffect`:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="All Tasks">
    <TextBlock.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1.2" 
                          Direction="270" 
                          Opacity="0.6" 
                          BlurRadius="1" 
                          Color="Red"/>
    </TextBlock.Effect>
</TextBlock>
```

This produces the following output:

[image: output]

If I set any Background color for the `TextBlock`, the shadow should disappear:

[image: output]

How can I set this property while keeping the drop shadow?

Comment: I believe it is because you're using a solid background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DropShadowEffect` doesn't disappear - it now applies to the whole rectangle.

This gives the desired effect:

```
<Border Background="Green">
    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="All Tasks">
        <TextBlock.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1.2" 
                              Direction="270" 
                              Opacity="0.6" 
                              BlurRadius="1" 
                              Color="Red"/>
        </TextBlock.Effect>
    </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain why WPF has this behavior?